# Include html inside of <?php if echo " "

Tags: php, if-statement, include, echo

pretty new to PHP as well, I am trying to have a php load a file dynamically depending an ID that added to the page. The idea is to have one file for multiple pages... I have multiple pages loading different sidebars:

```
<?php

if ($PageType == 'about'){
    echo "
         <img src='http://test.com/images/img.png' alt='' title='' class='img' />
         include('../include-images.html'); 
         <a href='#'><img src='test.com/images/one.jpg' alt='' title='' class='img' /></a>
         <br class='brclear'/>
         ";
}
```

Any help how to run that `INCLUDE('../include-images.html');` inside `<?php if echo ""` ?

Comment: End your echo; call `include`; echo out the rest of the HTML

Comment: *Sidenote:* `include` will try to include a file but doesn't throw an error if it's unsuccessful, and that's why you should use `require` because if it couldn't load the page, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do an `include` inside an `echo`. Just break up the `echo`:

```
<?php

if ($PageType == 'about'){
    echo "<img src='http://test.com/images/img.png' alt='' title='' class='img' />";
    include('../include-images.html'); 
    echo "<a href='#'><img src='test.com/images/one.jpg' alt='' title='' class='img' /></a>
                            <br class='brclear'/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply break echo and include html you need and thats it

```
if ($PageType == 'about'){
    echo "<img src='http://test.com/images/img.png' alt='' title='' class='img' />";
    include('../include-images.html');
    echo "<a href='#'><img src='test.com/images/one.jpg' alt='' title='' class='img' /></a>
                            <br class='brclear'/>
";
}
```

Or even better I like more

```
<?php
if ($PageType == 'about'){
?>
<img src='http://test.com/images/img.png' alt='' title='' class='img' />
<?php    
    include('../include-images.html'); 
?>
<a href='#'><img src='test.com/images/one.jpg' alt='' title='' class='img' /></a>
<br class='brclear'/>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot  get PHP to run the `include` when it is inside a string literal, so do this instead.

```
echo "<img src='http://test.com/images/img.png' alt='' title='' class='img' />";

include('../include-images.html'); 

echo "<a href='#'><img src='test.com/images/one.jpg' alt='' title='' class='img' /></a>
     <br class='brclear'/>
     ";
```

Also if you are getting the image from your own site, dont use the full domainname in the `src=`, just use the relative path

```
echo "<img src='images/img.png' alt='' title='' class='img' />";

include('../include-images.html'); 

echo "<a href='#'><img src='images/one.jpg' alt='' title='' class='img' /></a>
     <br class='brclear'/>
     ";
```

Then if you move the code to a new domain name you do not have to change the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<? if($PageType == 'about') { ?>

<img src='http://test.com/images/img.png' alt='' title='' class='img' />

<? include('../include-images.html'); ?>

<a href='#'><img src='test.com/images/one.jpg' alt='' title='' class='img' /></a>

<br class='brclear'/>

<? } ?>
```